# How to write code more elegantly? (Factorials, BigDecimals, division by BigIntegers)

Tags: java, math, biginteger, bigdecimal, factorial

I've managed to make my code working, but feel like there's a better approach to writing similar stuff, any tips or mistakes to point out?

Here's my code:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.##E0");
        BigDecimal a;
        BigInteger fact;
        int n=10;
        int x=3;

        for (int i=1; i<=n; i++){
            fact=BigInteger.valueOf(1);
            for (int j=1; j<=Math.pow(i,2)+1; j++){
            fact=fact.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(j));
            }
        a=BigDecimal.valueOf((Math.pow(-1, i+1)*Math.log(i*x))/i).divide(new BigDecimal(fact), 500, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
        System.out.println(df.format(a));
        }
    }
```

[image: Was calculating these numbers]

Comment: I think this belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yes.  Most of the things that I could say about this code are "style" issues, which would make this (arguably) a question that requires "opinion based" answers.

Comment: The other answer is that there is no substantially  "better way" in terms of your use of Java language constructs.  (But that is an opinion too.)

Comment: One little nitpick: `i*i` is probably faster and easier than `Math.pow(i,2)` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the following improvements:

- You can reduce the number of multiplications from `O(n^3)` to `O(n^2)` by starting with the value of `fact` from the previous iteration and multiply only with the missing values for `j`.
- As mentioned in the comments, `Math.pow(i,2)` is an overkill; same holds for `Math.pow(-1,i+1)`.
- use BigDecimal.ONE

Together with some minor changes this gives:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.##E0");
  int n = 10;
  int x = 3;
  int scale = 500;

  BigInteger fact = BigInteger.ONE;
  int rangeEndPrev = 0;
  int sign = 1;
  for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
  {
    int rangeEnd = i*i + 1;
    for (int j = rangeEndPrev + 1; j <= rangeEnd; j++)
      fact = fact.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(j));
    BigDecimal a1 = BigDecimal.valueOf((sign * Math.log(i * x)) / i);
    BigDecimal a  = a1.divide(new BigDecimal(fact), scale, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
    System.out.println(df.format(a));
    rangeEndPrev = rangeEnd;
    sign = -sign;
  }
}
```